# Is there an existing online emulator for Blackberry browser?

Tags: blackberry, mobile, blackberry-simulator

I'm triying to find a good emulator for the Blackberry browser, so I can try my blackberry app.

Is there an online version so I don't have to download and install one ?
Or in worse case scenario, which one should I download ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RIM provides a few simulators. They can be downloaded from http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp

I believe you need to register with them to download, but the registration is free.

Answer (score 2):

There's a free tool (Chrome Extension) called **[Ripple](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/)** (which was bought by RIM):

> Test and debug your HTML5 mobile applications for multiple platforms.
> All from within your browser and in a fraction of the time.

Also check out their playbook emulators: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/